# Django - Disqus not recognizing unique identifier

Tags: python, django, disqus

Basically, the same Disqus comments are showing up for every post. I've read about why this occurs, and still cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Here's what I'm seeing on my page:
    [image: 1]

And here's my template code:

```
{% block content %}
    <p> The post id is: {{ post_object.id}} </p>
    <p> The post URL: {{ post_object.get_absolute_url }}


    {# DISQUS #}
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'MySiteName'; // required
    var disqus_identifier = '{{ post_object.id }}';
    var disqus_url = 'http://localhost:8000{{ post_object.get_absolute_url }}';
    var disqus_title = '{{ post_object.title }}';
    var disqus_developer = 1;        

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
{% endblock content %}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'MySiteName'; // required
var disqus_identifier = '42';
var disqus_url = 'http://localhost:8000/post/42/';
var disqus_title = 'Test post';
var disqus_developer = 1;

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

As you can see, the disqus_identifier and disqus_url are unique. What is going on here?

Any ideas or feedback help! Thanks!

---

EDIT: Alright, I see where the problem is coming from. After posting on a comment on a post located at say `http://localhost:8000/post/42/`, Disqus adds to the Disqus admin (under the 'Discussions tab') the link to the post as `http://localhost:8000/post`

This is not even a valid URL on my page. When I explicitly change the link to `http://localhost:8000/post/42/`, it saves. However, a newly created post will still display the comments from post 42.

Thoughts?

Comment: What does the HTML of the rendered template look like? Are the variables substituted as you expect?

Comment: Good thought. I added that above, however it appears as it should.

Comment: I think I see where my problems lies. On Disqus's Admin site, under 'Discussions' tab, it is assigning the post the url `http://localhost:8000/post`. All of the posts are located at `http://localhost:8000/post/SOME_NUMBER`, therefore since all posts are subsets of the `/post` domain, the comments aren't unique to a post.

Comment: @chipperdrew, did you find out why the url was showing up as `/post` in Discussions tab? I'm having the same issue, spent hours on it so far, extremely frustrating

Comment: Can you try on a staging server? Disqus might check the response on the URL you're providing...

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475821/disqus-comments-fails-to-load-on-localhost (the most recent response, not the accepted one)

Comment: @dm03514 I never figured it out. I ended up giving up on Disqus since it was frustrating me so much. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Should the question be closed then? We won't be able to get a confirmation of the answer if the person asking has left the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Install [django-disqus](http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and use it in your templates.

```
pip install django-disqus
```

Add disqus to your INSTALLED_APPS and put your disqus api key in your settings:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'disqus',
    ...
)

DISQUS_API_KEY = 'YOUR_SECRET_API_KEY'
DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME = 'YOUR_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME'
```

Use disqus template tags in your templates:

some_template.html

```
# load the tags
{% load disqus_tags %}
# get comments for your website
{% disqus_show_comments "YOUR_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME" %}
# get the url for the current object to get the right comments
{% set_disqus_url object.get_absolute_url %}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could try using something like [django-disqus](http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which uses simple template tags for loading disqus comments. All it takes is:

```
# for when using the development server 

{% load disqus_tags %}
{% disqus_dev %}

# for showing all comments of a thread in production

{% load disqus_tags %}
{% disqus_show_comments %}
```